# Trigger a CSS animation in one component from a distant component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have a quite complex React16/Redux single page application.

I am trying to find a way to trigger a CSS animation on a component or DOM element (let's call it `Foo` component), when a user pushes a button (let's call it `Bar` component) which stands 'far away' from this `component`/`DOM element`.

I would like to avoid to pass through a list of callbacks, or through Redux, with a kind of `observer pattern`, so that I can do something like:

```js
class Bar extends React.Component {
    ...
    onButtonClick() {
        allFooComponentsOnThePageShouldBlinkFor1Second();
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: This really sounds like a job for Redux. Why don't you want to handle this that way?

Comment: I wanted to avoid all the redux overhead of writing actions/reducers etc...

Answer (score 0):

So, your best bet is probably to use Redux, or a similar state management system. That said, you can do this by using a wrapper component's local state as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689648/react-how-to-pass-state-to-another-component). I don't think this will be faster or easier in the long run than using Redux, but here we go:

Your component `Wrapper` will have some local state which keeps track of whether `Bar` should be flashing and has a function that changes that state which is passed to `Foo`. You need to be careful to make sure that the `this` in the click handler always points to `Wrapper`. I've done it here with an arrow function. If you would rather use `.bind`, then you can make that change in your implementation.

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    // accessible through `this.state`
    state = { fooShouldBlink: false };

    handleClick = () => {
        // arrow function preserves `this` as `Wrapper`
        this.setState({ fooShouldBlink: true }, () => {
            // Resets state after 1 second so that this can be done more than once. 
            // If that's not needed, you can take this out
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({ fooShouldBlink: false }), 1000);
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Bar clickHandler={this.handleClick}/>
                <Foo blinkState={this.state.fooShouldBlink} />
                <Foo blinkState={this.state.fooShouldBlink} />
                <Foo blinkState={this.state.fooShouldBlink} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```